# EF not creating table for virtual properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF with code-first. My model contains two virtual properties like:

```
ClassA

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual List<int> Teams { get; set; }
public virtual List<int> Levels { get; set; }
```

EF has created db tables for me there is only ClassA table. There is no table I can store Teams and Levels data. When I run Add-Migration command, created migration file is empty is EF thinks there is no pending changes. Also when I run Update-Database command EF says there is no pending changes.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't have an int as an entity that maps to a table.

Comment: Why would there be extra tables? You haven't defined them, or at least didn't show them in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do:

```
public class Team { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
public class Level { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
public class Player {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }
}
```

---

In case you really want 'light weight' (please don't) you could do:

```
public class Player {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //use comma separated values (starting and ending with ,)
    public string Teams { get; set; } 
    public string Levels { get; set; }
}
```

Say you have these in your context

```
var player1 = new Player(){Teams = ",1,2,"}
var player2 = new Player(){Teams = ",3,2,"}
```

Now, you could get both in team 2 by

```
var players = context.Players.Where(p=>p.Teams.Contains(",2,"));
```